# How to upload videos to JWplayer server from android programmatically

Tags: java, android, python, ios, jwplayer

I am using JW player in my Android application. Is there any way to upload videos from my client side(Android app) to JWplayer Server? I gone through 
your site https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/docs/developer-guide/management-api/uploading-videos/ to upload videos but its not clear that the code given is to upload the videos from android app or from a intermediate server.

Any clarifications on this would be greatly appreciated.

What we tried from our android app side is to upload the videos using below,

POST URL : `http://upload.jwplatform.com/v1/videos/upload?api_format=json&key=vtQmcboj&token=e2bbad0fd889d5d2e30047596cfe3789778257d2`

The params i sent,

```
api_key

api_secret

local_video_path
```

Comment: did you manage to make it work @KarthikKPN? can you share the code please?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot upload videos directly to JW player since its a Two tier process.
I have been workign in a java application where the user can upload videos, watch it and download it.

You will have to send the key and the token for the auth request, which JWplayer thinks is not safe from their end so they just will not allow you to upload the videos to their server.

To acheive the scenario, **you must be running your own server** which instead upload the video to the JW platform. All the error responses will have to be handled in your server side if the upload gets failed.

Also, JW player handles resumable upload process. So, once you sent the data to your server, your server can send the data in small units and the interruption in connection will be handled in JWplayer end.

In my own scenario, my server will be handling the resumable uploads from client(since its not possible to resume uploads from client without having valid protocols embedded in Server side) and my it indeeds send the data's to the JW player for encoding.

To be more precise,

Client ----> Your server ----> JW player server.

The POST method URI which you tried is for server side coding and not meant for client side. You can refer their support team for more details, since i came to know these details after reaching out them.

Answer (score 0):

As @DeadSpider answered,
`It is not possible from client side`. Go for a server and once you get it work, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday i got a demo project from JWplayer and it is absolutely possible now to upload videos to your dashboad from client side.

http://qa.jwplayer.com.s3.amazonaws.com/~george/BishopQA.zip

Check the above project and in upload activity you will have the code. Its working for both android and ios platforms.